# Conditional import in kivy/python on android with python for android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Base is a python3/kivy apk created with p4a for android.

I tried to use conditional import:

```py
import sys
if 'linux' in sys.platform:
    from DruckLinux import Druck
else:
    from DruckAndroid import Druck
```

where DruckAndroid is ignored in blacklist.txt. So it's not copied to the device. Would give additional errors with dependencies (python-escpos) as well.

But I get

```
04-24 20:38:04.850  7235  7261 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-24 20:38:04.850  7235  7261 I python  :    File "/home/pille/src/mvo_pos/main.py", line 5, in <module>
04-24 20:38:04.851  7235  7261 I python  :    File "/home/pille/src/mvo_pos/Produktwahl.py", line 29, in <module>
04-24 20:38:04.851  7235  7261 I python  :    File "/home/pille/src/mvo_pos/Druckbasis.py", line 3, in <module>
04-24 20:38:04.851  7235  7261 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DruckLinux'
04-24 20:38:04.851  7235  7261 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

So why is this evaluated on my android device?

When commenting out the import all works fine. But I would like to do this with a conditional import.

Regards
Thomas

Comment: I think sys.platform evaluates to whatever it would have been on the platform you compiled python. You can use `kivy.platform` instead.

Comment: Using kivy.platform instead of sys.platform helped. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using kivy instead of sys like @inclement suggested was the solution

```py
import kivy
if 'linux' in kivy.platform:
    from DruckLinux import Druck
else:
    from DruckAndroid import Druck
```